# VOM617AT SPICE model not working

Tags: ltspice, simulation, opto-isolator, spice, pspice

I downloaded the VOM617AT (optocoupler) SPICE model from the following address:

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/VOM617AT?qs=9vrc9xEJKyxW%252B%2FlvaQ%252BSPg%3D%3D

I am not quite sure why it's named as `BJT_5mA`. Then I tried to import it to Microcap, and I am unable to do so. Microcap can't find a spice model in this file, but I do see "subckt" text in the file. Previously, I have successfully imported spice models from Mouser/Digikey. Is something wrong with this spice model? Here's a copy of the spice model in text:

```
* Library of DC Input Phototransistor Output Optocoupler BJT_5mA
* Copyright VISHAY, Inc. 2018 All Rights Reserved.
*
* ==== BJT_5mA ====
* A = diode anode
* K = diode cathode
* C = BJT collector
* E = BJT emitter
*$
.SUBCKT BJT_5mA A K C E PARAMS: REL_CTR=1
D1 A D DIRED    ;IRED
Vsense D K 0 ;IF Current sense
Hd R 0 Vsense 1 ;I-V
Rd R T 10K
Cd T 0 0.2n
Rdummy B 0 4G
Q1 C B E [E] QBJT ;phototransistor
* V-I
Gpcg C B TABLE  ;Photodetector {(IC vs IF) / Q1 BF}
+ {0.4*REL_CTR*(V(T)**1.658*exp(limit(4.3-60*V(T),-50,50))*
+ ((4*10**(-9)*(REL_CTR**6))-(7*10**(-7)*(REL_CTR**5))+(5*10**(-5)*(REL_CTR**4))-(0.0015*(REL_CTR**3))+
+ (0.023*(REL_CTR**2))-(0.155*(REL_CTR))+2.2261)/100)}
+ (0,0) (10,10)
.model DIRED D IS=1P N=1.948621 BV=6 IBV=10U
+ CJO=18.8P EG=1.424 TT=500N
.model QBJT NPN IS=3.64P BF=100 NF=1.193293 BR=10 TF=13N TR=350n
+ CJE=5.16P CJC=18P VAF=65 ISS=0 CJS=7.74p
.ends
*$
**==================================================================*
* Note:
* Although models can be a useful tool in evaluating device performance,
* they cannot model exact device performance under all conditions, nor
* are they intended to replace breadboarding for final verification.
* Models provided by VISHAY Semiconductors GmbH (“Vishay”) do not represent
* all of the specifications and operating characteristics of the product to
* which the model relates. The models attempt to describe the characteristics
* of typical products. The current data sheet information for a given
* product represents the final design guideline and includes actual
* performance specifications. The accuracy, reliability and compatibility
* of models provided by Vishay are not guaranteed or warranted in any way
* and Vishay disclaims liability of any kind whatsoever, including, without
* limitation, liability for quality, performance, merchantability and fitness
* for a particular purpose arising out of the use, or inability to use a model.
* Vishay reserves the right to change models without prior notice.
* The products described herein, including the model and any results produced
* using the model, are subject to the specific disclaimers set forth at www.vishay.com/doc?91000.
**===================================================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SPICE model can be found at [Vishay's web site](https://www.vishay.com/en/product/83446/tab/designtools-ppg/) which is what I would download instead of a model at a third party's web site.

It looks like the BJT_5mA.lib file is in <s>UTF-8</s> UCS-2 encoding. Perhaps Microcap doesn't understand <s>UTF-8</s> UCS-2. If so, you'll need to transform the file to ASCII which Libreoffice Writer does, as well as many other programs. You need to make your own symbol for Microcap. Lines 5 thru 10 of the model show the pin designations.

Comment: It was an issue about UTF-8 file format. I used an online tool and it was able to import the spice model without an issue. Thanks.

Comment: I did some more digging into this.  The file is actually in UCS-2 Little Endian encoding without a BOM (byte order mark).  Micro-Cap cannot understand the UCS-2 format, either with or without the BOM.  However, it can indeed process an actual UTF-8 file though, BOM or no BOM.  It's a shame Vishay supplies a library file written in 2018 with this obsolete UCS-2 format.  Hopefully it's not common throughout their other libraries...

Comment: @SteKulov  I've never heard of UCS-2. Thanks for the research.

Comment: @SteKulov UCS-2 is the encoding Windows uses natively, I believe. Much to the consternation of everyone else.

Comment: @Hearth  [I think that's close](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows).  What Windows (at least in XP and 7) refers to as "Unicode" is UCS-2.  If you use Notepad to save something as "Unicode" it ends up as UCS-2 w/ a BOM.  If you save it as "UTF-8", it will save it properly as UTF-8 (w/ a BOM).  I dunno, seems like UCS-2 and UTF-16 are used interchangeably, so maybe when Notepad++ reports UCS-2 it means UTF-16??? I just know that for the purposes of this discussion, MicroCap seems to reject text using a fixed two bytes per character representation.